# Хитрые классы на PHP 5.3 и 7

Tags: php, классы, php7

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять,есть ли опечатка в задании из технического собеседования:

**Задача 1, PHP >= 5.3.0**

```
/**
  Написать реализацию класса SimpleClass, при которой
  код, приведенный ниже напечатает Hellow world в консоль
*/
$obj = new SimpleClass;
$obj()->stdout('Hello')->stdout(' world');
```

Обратите внимание на скобки после вызова `$obj`:

> **`$obj()->`**

Если это не ошибка, то как реализовать такой класс?

---

А здесь вообще непонятно:

**Задача 2, PHP >= 7**

```
/**
 * Написать реализацию класса SimpleClass при которой вызов конструкции будет корректным.
 * Вызов без аргумента будет трактоваться как "печать перевода строки", так что данная конструкция

(new SimpleClass)('Hello')()('world')()('1');

 напечатает в консоль:

Hello
world
!

*/
```

Как такое может быть реализовано?

Comment: вставьте код в виде кода, а не картинки

Comment: Опечатки в задании нет. А просить решить за вас задачи с собеседования - не спортивно.

Comment: в первом задании каждый метод возвращает `$this`.... читай про цепочку методов

Comment: во втором видимо метод возвращает сам себя...но это не точно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в первом речь про `obj()` и скобки применительно к объекту класса, а не цепочку вызовов, т..е про invoke

Comment: самая подстава будет, если ревьювер тоже сидит на SO :D бгг :)

Comment: @teran не увидел. почему-то сразу посмотрел на `stdout`. ...но даже `invoke` должен вернуть себя, а дальше по накатной. `invoke` — метод. в итоге получается цепочка методов )

Comment: @teran кстати, а во втором задании причем тут PHP 7? Из-за подряд идущих круглых скобок? Я просто не помню, к чему это относится и почему на версиях ниже не сработает?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev и всё-таки всегда найдется [↓ ↓ ↓](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688290/191482) :)

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev собеседование дано прошло. Я просто хочу разобраться в теме.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а я тоже хз, но тоже подумал на скобки. Видимо наравне с тем, что объявлять функцию и тут тут же выполнить `(f(){..})()` можно только в пхп7, с объектом видимо из той же оперы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используется магический метод [__invoke()](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke).

```
<?php

class SimpleClass
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function stdout ($str)
    {
        echo $str;

        return $this;
    }
}

$obj = new SimpleClass;
$obj()->stdout("Hello")->stdout(" world!");
```

---

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
    public function __invoke($str = PHP_EOL)
    {
        echo $str;

        return $this;
    }
}

(new SimpleClass)("Hello")()("world")()("!");
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.
А вы мне могли бы привести примеры, для чего вообще такое может понадобиться?
Зачем делать `$obj()->stdout("Hello")->stdout(" world!");` вместо `$obj->stdout("Hello")->stdout(" world!");`

Пример из PHP 7, видимо, для прикола...